# Jira Agile board sprint icon displays wrong point count

Tags: jira, jira-agile

[image]

You can see the in progress icon display 76, but 76 is the resolved issue points, how do I fix this display issue

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate to your board and select 'Configure' you can update your board's "Column Configuration". On that page you map which statuses correspond to "Open" (blue), "In Progress" (yellow) and "Done" (green).

The page looks like this:
[image]

For more info, check the [Configuring Columns](https://confluence.atlassian.com/agile/jira-agile-user-s-guide/configuring-a-board/configuring-columns) documentation page.